# How to pass react module style to typeit-react function

Tags: css, reactjs, typeit

I am using [typeit-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeit-react) (animated typing utility) to animate typing effect. I have a problem to pass react module style to typeit-react function. Passing class as one usually do in React `className={styles.myReactClass}` does NOT work but this form `class="myClass"` works fine.

```js
import TypeIt from "typeit-react";
import styles from "./index.module.css";

<TypeIt
    getBeforeInit={(instance) => {
        instance
            .type('<span class="myClass">Hello World!</span>')                    # THIS DOES WORK!
            .pause(750)
            .type('<span className={styles.myReactClass}">Hello World!</span>')   # THIS DOES NOT WORK!
        return instance;
    }}
/>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because that `type` function accepts *string*, not a *JSX* element.

The solution is to get the class name in the beforehand in the component context and pass it to the *type* function as string.

```
import TypeIt from "typeit-react";
import styles from "./index.module.css";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const spanClass = styles.myReactClass;
  
  return (
    <TypeIt
      getBeforeInit={(instance) => {
        instance
          .type('<span class="myClass">Hello World!</span>')
          .pause(750)
          .type(`<span class="${spanClass}">Hello World!</span>`);
        return instance;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

If you really wants to pass a jsx element, you can use `renderToStaticMarkup` from `react-dom/server` to convert it to string

```
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from "react-dom/server";


<TypeIt
  getBeforeInit={(instance) => {
    instance
      .type('<span class="myClass">Hello World!</span>')
      .pause(750)
      .type(
        renderToStaticMarkup(
          <span className={styles.myAnotherReactClass}>
            `type` types a JSX element!
          </span>
        )
      );
    return instance;
  }}
/>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typeit-with-css-modules-m0l33k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: As suggested I got the class name first in the component context and passed it to the type function as string. It works fine except the style of cursor, i.e., the height of cursor does not match to letters and its style. How can I fix it?

Comment: P.S. I have tried to define values of cursor variables in react module styles (e.g. ```--ti-cursor-font-size: 4.8rem;```) as in [docs](https://www.typeitjs.com/docs/vanilla/cursor-customization/#cursor-styling) not it does not help.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox (or fork mine) so I could play with it?

Comment: Here please a fork of your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typeit-with-css-modules-forked-8usoz8?file=/src/README.md).

Comment: As mentioned in the doc, you can "customize these values as needed by setting the value for a property (the css variables) in your CSS - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typeit-with-css-modules-forked-efhioh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That is unfortunately the problem, I can not override css variable introduced in root (e.g. ```--ti-cursor-font-size```) in my css class . Check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typeit-with-css-modules-forked-94hgzg?file=/src/index.module.css). To be more precise: it affects font style but NOT cursor style.

Comment: That's right. Because the cursor is not under the span with the `styles.myAnotherReactClass` scope, the css changes don't apply on it. Do you want to change the size of the typed text as it typed? There is a workaround but it's not recommended because it relays on a typeit class which might change. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typeit-with-css-modules-forked-30wo91?file=/src/index.module.css. It's not working perfectly as well